# Connect to Mongo db with URI not work with parameter tlsAllowInvalidCertificates

Tags: mongodb

I try to connect to mongo with the following uri:

```
mongo 'mongodb://mongoadmin:mxmxmxmxm@server:27017/?tls=true&tlsInvalidHostNameAllowed=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1'
```

but anyway server validate the certificate:

```
2020-07-30T09:06:59.250-0400 E  NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED; connection rejected
2020-07-30T09:06:59.250-0400 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server bcicrtlmongodb001:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED; connection rejected :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17


in the server config file:
-- network interfaces
net:
  bindIpAll: true
  port: 27017


--  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca.f5.bci.cl.cer
    disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true

security:
   authorization: enabled 
   javascriptEnabled: false

setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Comment: Please format your post properly.

Answer (score -2):

Server and client validate each other's certificates independently.

`tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` is the client-side option for the client to not validate the server's certificate. It has no effect on whether the server validates the client's certificate, which is configured in server settings.